# Attach Card to Customer Record

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm currently learning the Stripe API with a test card and Test Secret Key. I'm attempting to create a test card token and then create a customer object with that card token. I plan on using that card token for future transactions.

I can successfully generate the card token using the `/v1/tokens` endpoint and then I can successfully create a customer using the `/vi/customers` endpoint. However, I can't seem to assign the token or card ID from the card token step to the customer in step 2.

I've attempted to use the `sources` attribute to reference the card token while creating the customer (the token ID nor the card ID seem to be working for me) and I've also attempted to run an update on the customer to attach the source card token without any issue. I've also attempted to create a new card object via `/v1/customers/:id/sources` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any advice on what steps I need to do to accomplish this via Stripe API only?

Comment: would be nice to see your coding efforts, working parts and not working parts and your expectations

Answer (score 0):

Using the token id, you should be able to attach this to the customer during creation with the [`source` (singular!) parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-source), for example `source=tok_123`. After creation, you would instead make a separate [attach](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/attach) call:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_345/sources \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  -d source=src_567
```

Instead of this, though, I'd recommend using our updated Payment Method and [Setup Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) APIs to [save a card for future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) following this guide.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much and I also appreciate the additional guidance/context related to the Payment Methods